# Object list to String list

Tags: java, android

trying to convert a list of objects with mobile numbers to a list of string

```
contactsList1=response.body(); //this is an object list contactList1[Contacts]

contactsList2=new ArrayList<String>(contactsList.size()); // this is the new list String

for (Contacts contacts:contactsList){
    contactsList2.add(contacts!=null ? contacts.toString():null);
                    }
```

there is a problem in this code .

it didn't convert it from object list to list string any tips?

**Contacts.class**

```
public class Contacts {

    @SerializedName("phone")
    private String phone;


    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
}
```

Comment: post contact model structure

Comment: show the definition of your `toString` within the `Contacts` class. Note that if you don't override the `toString`, you'll be invoking the `Object` toString.

Comment: I edited my question and added it you can check it now

Comment: Call contacts.getPhone() to add it in your contactList2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with :

```
   contacts.toString()
```

You need to override toString method :

```
 @Override
    public String toString() {
        return phone;
    }
```